# Implement HwndHost to handle MouseMove and MouseWheel in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, interop, hwnd, hwndhost

I am trying to host DirectX content inside WPF app. What I learnt from this link is to subclass
HwndHost and create your own implementation of WndProc as well BuildWindowCore and DestroyWindowCore. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-win32-control-in-wpf#implement-a-class-to-host-the-microsoft-win32-control

I then found pretty much useful implemenation following the same here:
https://github.com/Smartrak/WpfSharpDxControl/blob/master/WpfSharpDxControl/Win32HwndControl.cs

Now, I need to implement two more methods such as WM_MOUSEMOVE (0x0200) and WM_MOUSEWHEEL (0x020A).
I am not sure how to do that properly to pass information such as mouse wheel delta and timestamp.
Any pointer in this direction would really be helpful.

```
protected override IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
            case NativeMethods.WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                //What should go here
                break;
            case NativeMethods.WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
                //What should go here
                break;
            case NativeMethods.WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                RaiseMouseEvent(MouseButton.Left, Mouse.MouseDownEvent);
                break;

            case NativeMethods.WM_LBUTTONUP:
                RaiseMouseEvent(MouseButton.Left, Mouse.MouseUpEvent);
                break;

            case NativeMethods.WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
                RaiseMouseEvent(MouseButton.Right, Mouse.MouseDownEvent);
                break;

            case NativeMethods.WM_RBUTTONUP:
                RaiseMouseEvent(MouseButton.Right, Mouse.MouseUpEvent);
                break;
        }

        return base.WndProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam, ref handled);
    }
```

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: This is winapi, you have to look into msdn (e.g. [WM_MOUSEMOVE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645616(v=vs.85).aspx)), then you know details regarding `lParam` and `wParam`, e.g. in case of `WM_MOUSEMOVE` you will need to extract signed low and high word (16 bits) of `lParam` to get x and y coordinate of mouse position in client units (relative to hwnd window).

Comment: Thanks @Sinatr. I will try it out now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer and exact implementation I wanted here:

https://github.com/tgjones/gemini/blob/master/src/Gemini/Framework/Controls/HwndWrapper.cs

It just works perfect. If you get OverFlow exception for NativeMethods.GetWheelDeltaWParam(Convert.ToInt32(value));

Use 
NativeMethods.GetWheelDeltaWParam(Convert.ToInt64(value));

Full credit to Tim Jones for this awesome github repo and work!
https://github.com/tgjones